# SQL Using Between for two tables

Tags: sql, db2, between

Hi I want to fetch data from a Table based on values that lie between two columns of another table, below SQL shoulde explain my purpose:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 1 WHERE 1.FIELD1 BETWEEN 
(SELECT 2.RANGE_FROM FROM TABLE 2) AND (SELECT 2.RANGE_TO FROM TABLE 2)
```

This is not working as I am getting error:

```
Error: SQL0811N  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.  SQLSTATE=21000
 (State:21000, Native Code: FFFFFCD5)
```

This is obvious as both the subqueries return multiple rows. So I want to write a SQL to perform above function without error.
The platform is `IBM DB2`.

**EDIT**:

Ok I think I solved this one by joining 2 tables using the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B WHERE A.FIELD1 BETWEEN B.RANGE_FROM AND B.RANGE_TO
```

More testing is required though.

Comment: do you have any relation between table1 and table2?

Comment: No relation. The first table has proper setup values, and 2nd table contains range from and range to values. For example, table 1 has a row value of 1000, and 2nd table has 900 and 1200 in range_from and range_to field, then my query should return that row from table 1.

Comment: What is the expected result? The way you wrote the query the two subqueries *must* return exactly one value. If the first row of `TABLE 1` should be matched against the first row of `TABLE 2` and the 2nd with the other 2nd, then you must define a relation and `JOIN` the two tables.

Comment: Re: your edit, this will return duplicate rows from `A` if `A.FIELD1` fits in more than one range in table `B`.  That is something to keep in mind in your design (The solution provided below by ypercube avoids this issue).

Comment: Yeah I will give Distinct in Select.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you want to check if the table1 column values are between the 2 columns of (some row of) table2:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TABLE1 AS a 
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM TABLE2 AS b 
        WHERE a.FIELD1 BETWEEN b.RANGE_FROM AND b.RANGE_TO
      ) ;
```

This way, you'll have no duplicates from `table1`, so there is no need for `DISTINCT`.

Also note that the condition:

```
a.FIELD1 BETWEEN b.RANGE_FROM AND b.RANGE_TO
```

is equivalent to:

```
b.RANGE_FROM <= a.FIELD1  AND  a.FIELD1 <= b.RANGE_TO
```

Comment: Inside an EXISTS subquery it doesn't matter what you put in the SELECT list, because the EXISTS expression returns either TRUE (exists at least 1 row) or FALSE (not even 1 row exists). Some prefer to use `SELECT *`, others `SELECT 1`. I've even seen the rather confusing `SELECT NULL`. Some DBMS (Postgres) even allow empty select list (just `SELECT`). Whatever you use, it makes no difference on the result of the query. I suggest you use whatever makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

The values used in between clause should be scalar values. As your sub queries are returning multiple rows, therefore the query is failing. Try refining your sub queries to return just one result. For this first decide what value of range_from and range_to from table2 should your field lie in between of. Try min of range_from and max of range_to, or apply where caluse in your subquery depending on your requirement.