# Hive: Get the rows from a table by mapping rows from another table having no common columns

Tags: hive, conditional-statements, hiveql

I have two tables.

Table 1:

timestamp

Table 2:

timestamp_lower_bound, 
timestamp_upper_bound

I want to select rows from Table 1 if the timestamp is in between the lower bound and upper bound in Table 2 in hive.

I tried the following code.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
where from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') 
BETWEEN (select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp_lower_bound, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') from Table2) 
AND (select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp_upper_bound, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') from Table2)
```

And it give the error below.

```
DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
```

I also followed in the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706638/sql-using-between-for-two-tables) on stackoverflow and here is the code. It also failed due to vertex failure.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 AS a
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM Table2 AS b
     WHERE a.timestamp BETWEEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(b.timestamp_lb, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') 
     AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(b.timestamp_ub, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') )
```

Any idea on how to do this? Not necessary to do it in Hive, Spark also works. Any idea?

**EIDT**

Here is a toy example.

Suppose in Table 1 timestamp, I have the following.

```
|---------------------|
|    Timestamp        |  
|---------------------|
|  2018-01-15 17:56   | 
|---------------------|
|  2019-04-29 08:43   | 
|---------------------|
|  2018-10-23 23:43   | 
|---------------------|
|  2018-08-21 04:54   | 
|---------------------|
|  2019-12-06 14:09   | 
|---------------------|
```

In Table 2, I have the following upper bounds and lower bounds.

```
|----------------------|------------------------|
|timestamp_lower_bound |timestamp_upper_bound   |
|----------------------|------------------------|
|  2018-04-15 12:37    |  2018-04-15 12:57      |
|----------------------|------------------------|
|  2018-10-23 23:38    |  2018-10-23 23:58      |
|----------------------|------------------------|
|  2018-08-21 04:50    |  2018-08-21 05:10      |
|----------------------|------------------------|
```

In this case, only the third and fourth record in Table 1 should be selected. How shall I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

As per the above example, It clearly indicate that 'Table2' contain same data in both the column(timestamp_lower_bound and timestamp_upper_bound) i.e Date, only 'HH:MM' can be changed or only 'MM' can be changed.

its not necessary to scan both the column if we scan only one column it will suffice.

For e.g:

```
create table table1
(TTimestamp string);

insert into table1 values('2018-01-15 17:56');
insert into table1 values('2019-04-29 08:43');
insert into table1 values('2018-10-23 23:43');
insert into table1 values('2018-08-21 04:54');
insert into table1 values('2019-12-06 14:09');

create table table2
(timestamp_lower_bound string,
timestamp_upper_bound  string);

insert into table2 values('2018-04-15 12:37','2018-04-15 12:57');
insert into table2 values('2018-10-23 23:43','2018-10-23 23:58');
insert into table2 values('2018-08-21 04:54','2018-08-21 05:10');
```

```
select TTimestamp from table1 where TTimestamp in(select timestamp_lower_bound from table2);

TTimestamp
2018-08-21 04:54
2018-10-23 23:43
```

Here, I have taken datatype as a string and inserted the record as it is.In your case you can use below query.

```
select TTimestamp from table1 where from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') in(select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp_lower_bound, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') from table2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact, Table 1 is a large table while Table 2 is very small. About your suggested code, when applying min / max operator, the "between and" clause actually connects two values, instead of two columns of values, right? But I would like to get timestamp in Table 1 that is in between of EACH pair of lower bound and upper bound in Table 2.

Comment: @Tracy Yang, Can you please elaborate your questions with proper example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I updated my question by including a toy example. Let me know if you have any idea.